# Node.js Redis Module: Passing an Array to HSET?

Tags: node.js, npm, redis

I'm upgrading some Node.js code from [redis@3.x to redis@4.x](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis).  When I try to run code that looks like this

```
client.hSet(['hash key', 'hashtest 2', 'some other value']).then(function (reply) {
  /* ... */
});
```

I get the following error

```
/path/to/node_modules/@redis/client/dist/lib/commands/HSET.js:37
    for (const key of Object.keys(object)) {
                             ^

TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Function.keys (<anonymous>)
    at pushObject (/path/to/node_modules/@redis/client/dist/lib/commands/HSET.js:37:30)
    at Object.transformArguments (/path/to/node_modules/@redis/client/dist/lib/commands/HSET.js:17:9)
    at transformCommandArguments (/path/to/node_modules/@redis/client/dist/lib/commander.js:71:23)
    at Commander.commandsExecutor (/path/to/node_modules/@redis/client/dist/lib/client/index.js:169:88)
    at BaseClass.<computed> [as hSet] (/path/to/node_modules/@redis/client/dist/lib/commander.js:8:29)
    at /path/to/test/instrumentation/modules/redis.test.js:118:12
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

I'm curious what's going on.  Does redis@4.x no longer support passing an array as an argument to `hSet` like redis@3.x did?  This [isn't mentioned in the docs](https://github.com/redis/node-redis/blob/master/docs/v3-to-v4.md).

I know I can switch to either of the following

```
client.hSet('hash key', 'hashtest 2', 'some other value').then(function (reply) {
  /* ... */
});

client.hSet(...['hash key', 'hashtest 2', 'some other value']).then(function (reply) {
  /* ... */
});
```

to get things working, but I'm curious what's going on here and if there's still a way to pass an array to hSet.  (the docs, [as far as I can see](https://github.com/redis/node-redis/tree/master/docs), don't make mention of what arguments are accepted)

Comment: The failure seems to be in the [default Object handler](https://github.com/redis/node-redis/blob/b10a6567dc84803baff6e34ed9efa1199ac3c283/packages/client/lib/commands/HSET.ts#L29-L33) so I can only guess `Array.isArray` is not picking up the argument. Have you got any funky build processes involved?

Comment: No build involved other than npm install -- but there are some monkey patching agents active.  Thanks @matt -- that gives me a code point to start debugging backwards from. Useful, +1

Comment: Looks like a signature change from previous versions of redis (or perhaps the previous behavior never really worked) -- the `transformArgument` function @matt linked receives the entire array as the `key` argument -- so isArray never has a chance to see it.  Thanks again for the code point -- it helped me.

Comment: Oh so `value` was `undefined` hence Object.  The  `(...[k,v,f])` signature fooled me.  Must be some form of Typescript varargs trick?

Comment: Re: "some form of Typescript varargs trick" -- maybe.  I've learned not to dive too deep into older code bases refactored in place with TypeScript.  There Be Numerous Weird Dragons™